# "CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt: No project() command is present" While upgrading React Native 0.69 in Expo bare project

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, cmake, expo

I'm upgrading a react native app from RN0.68 -> RN 0.69. The app is using the expo bare workflow. Here's the CMake Error I'm seeing:

```
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE

> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env
**************************
*** Missing .env file ****
**************************

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-error-recovery (3.2.0)
  - expo-local-authentication (12.3.0)
  - expo-modules-core (0.11.10)
  - expo-secure-store (11.3.0)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.16.2)
  - expo-store-review (5.3.0)


> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
C/C++: prefabcom.google.prefab.api.NoMatchingLibraryException: No compatible library found for //fbjni/fbjni. Rejected the following libraries:
C/C++: prefabandroid.arm64-v8a: User is targeting x86 but library is for arm64-v8a
C/C++: prefabandroid.armeabi-v7a: User is targeting x86 but library is for armeabi-v7a
C/C++: prefabandroid.x86: User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL
C/C++: prefabandroid.x86_64: User is targeting x86 but library is for x86_64
C/C++: debug|x86 :CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
C/C++: debug|x86 :  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
C/C++: debug|x86 :  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
C/C++: debug|x86 :  code such as
C/C++: debug|x86 :    project(ProjectName)
C/C++: debug|x86 :  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
C/C++: debug|x86 :  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
C/C++: debug|x86 :  line.
C/C++: debug|x86 :This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
C/C++: debug|x86 :CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
C/C++: debug|x86 :Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
C/C++: debug|x86 :FBJNI_LIB
C/C++: debug|x86 :    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
C/C++: debug|x86 :FOLLY_LIB
C/C++: debug|x86 :    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
C/C++: debug|x86 :JSI_LIB
C/C++: debug|x86 :    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
C/C++: debug|x86 :REACT_NATIVE_JNI_LIB
C/C++: debug|x86 :    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
C/C++: debug|x86 :REACT_NATIVE_MODULES_CORE
C/C++: debug|x86 :    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
C/C++: debug|x86 :CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
[CXX1405] error when building with cmake using /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/etai/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=28 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-28 -DANDROID_ABI=x86 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=x86 -DANDROID_NDK=/Users/etai/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/etai/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/etai/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/etai/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2z33o1su/obj/x86 -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2z33o1su/obj/x86 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/2z33o1su/prefab/x86/prefab -B/Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/2z33o1su/x86 -GNinja -DREACT_NATIVE_DIR=/Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/react-native -DREACT_NATIVE_SO_DIR=/Users/etai/mobile/member/android/ReactAndroid/build/intermediates/library_*/*/jni -DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=69 -DBOOST_VERSION=1_76_0 -DUSE_HERMES=false -DHERMES_HEADER_DIR=null -DUNIT_TEST=false}
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Users/etai/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/etai/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
FBJNI_LIB
    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
FOLLY_LIB
    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
JSI_LIB
    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
REACT_NATIVE_JNI_LIB
    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
REACT_NATIVE_MODULES_CORE
    linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/etai/mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 22s
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date
```

Maybe relevant, I also ran into an issue around finding the React Native Dir

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-modules-core'.
> /Users/etai/mobile/member/android/ReactAndroid/gradle.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Which I resolved by replacing this line with a hardcoded string path.

```
REACT_NATIVE_DIR = REACT_NATIVE_BUILD_FROM_SOURCE
  ? findProject(":ReactAndroid").getProjectDir().parent
  : new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).parent
```

Here's what I'm working with:

- M1 Mac
- XCode 14.2 in Rosetta mode
- React Native 0.68.5 -> 0.69.7
- expo (Bare) 46.0.21
- expo-modules-core 0.11.5 -> 0.11.10
- *an unusual directory structure that sometimes causes problems `/Root+Package.json/UnnecessaryFolder/android`*

Comment: You're missing several dependencies. They're listed in your error message.

Comment: @nega. Yes, I am missing dependencies. The cmake file is in node_modules/expo-modules-core and it relies on info provided by node_modules/react-native. I don't know how to give it the dependencies it wants so it all hooks properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18683#issuecomment-1463742142

Within the expo-modules-core build.gradle file, remove this block of code:

```
externalNativeBuild {
  cmake {
    if (REACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION >= 71) {
      path "CMakeLists.txt"
    } else {
      path "legacy/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
  }
}
```